# Does Lollipop use LLVM to get OAT file?

Tags: android, compilation, llvm, android-5.0-lollipop, bytecode

Which compiler does Android lollipop use to convert dex bytecode to oat? I read somewhere that it uses LLVM but I also referred some docs about Quick compiler.
Finally, which one is used in current tree? I believe it is not vendor specific.

Comment: The compiler is called ART.

Comment: No, ART means Android Runtime which is not a compiler. Runtime and compiler have different jobs to do and they are not same.